# Sanic unit testing for file uploads

Tags: python, unit-testing, web-services, python-unittest, sanic

The below is a snippet of code that summarizes how I am posting a file to an endpoint on a Sanic app:

```
from sanic import Sanic, response

class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, test=False):
        self.app = Sanic()
        self.app.add_route(self.upload, '/upload', methods=['POST'])

    async def upload(self,request):
        # Obtain some data from the request to compare md5
        md5 = request.form.get('md5')

        # Check for file
        if not request.files.get('file'):
            return {"message":"No file selected!","success":False}
        test_file = request.files.get('file')
```

**How can I write a unit test which is able to pass in a file, md5 etc as part of the request object?** The following is what I have tried, but no luck:

```
from server import Server
import unittest

class TestUpload(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_upload(self):
        app = Server(test=True).app

        upload_payload = {'upload': open('upload_file.yaml', 'rb'), 'digest': '56d5b275ab20831b22f835cc7bf9905a'}
        headers = {"content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=------sanic"}
        files = {'file': ('upload', open('upload_file.yaml', 'rb'), 'text/yaml'), 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Content-Disposition': 'form-data; name="upload"; filename="upload_file.yaml"'}

        request, response = app.test_client.post("/upload", data=upload_payload, headers=headers, files=files)
```

As you can see above, I have tried a variety of methods to see if the request object created using the SanicTestClient would contain the file as part of the `request.files` and the custom `request.form.md5`, but those properties are never populated on the request that the SanicTestClient creates. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Project maintainer here. Did you see how we handle this in [Sanic unit tests](https://github.com/huge-success/sanic/blob/master/tests/test_requests.py#L1288)?